# How to spawn a new div prior to the last div in a container?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create new fields like the first field in this form by clicking on an image, but the fields are spawning below the button to submit and I don't understand why. The behavior I'm looking for is for the new fields to spawn above the button.

Here's my code

```
        <div id="title">
            <h1>Monthly Run Operations Assessment</h1>
        </div>


        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-20" id="row-one">
            <label for="name">1. </label>
          </div>

          <div class="col-60">
            <input type="text" id="op" name="op" placeholder="Insert operation here">
          </div>

          <div class="col-20" id="symbol">
              <img src="file:///C:/Users/user/Downloads/plus-circle-solid.svg" id="add">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="submit">
          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </div>

    </div>
```

This is the function:

```
var element = document.getElementById("add");
element.onclick = function() {
    console.log("woot");
    var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("row")[0];
    var clone = ele.cloneNode(true);
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    document.body.appendChild(clone);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I combined the above answers to achieve the expected behavior.

```
var element = document.getElementById("add");
element.onclick = function() {
  // console.log("woot");
  var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("row")[0];
  var clone = ele.cloneNode(true);
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  document.querySelector('#container').insertBefore(clone, ele);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`appendChild`, as its name suggests, always appends the new element -- that is, it adds it to the end. What you want is `insertBefore`:

```
document.body.insertBefore(clone, ele);
```

Comment: `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.` this is what I get with your solution. Thanks!

Comment: If you do `console.log(ele)`, what do you see in the console? (Also, side note: you're not doing anything with `newDiv`, so you may as well not waste memory creating it every time.)

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: ele is not defined`

Comment: ? Where are you putting this code? Because according to the code you posted, you're defining ele right here: `var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("row")[0];`

Comment: It's due to scope. I moved that out of the anonymous function, and it shows `<div class="row">`

Comment: But even after that: `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.`

Comment: "It's due to scope. I moved that out of the nameless function, and it shows <div class="row">" Uh... is there some code you're not showing us? There is zero reason the variable wouldn't be accessible inside the same anonymous function it's defined in. Where are you putting the console.log relative to the definition of `ele`, and where are you putting `document.body.insertBefore(clone, ele)`? They should both be inside the anonymous function and after the ele definition.

Comment: Nope. There's no other code I'm not showing you. I'm substituting my `document.body.appendChild(ele)` with your `document.body.insertBefore(clone, ele)`, and with or without the `var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("row")[0];` inside the anonymous function, the behavior is the same. And the error is `nodecreator.js:11 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.`

Comment: I combined your suggestion with @Taki's, and achieved the behavior I wanted. Will update with an answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle this is to wrap your form in a `container` and append to it :

```js
var element = document.getElementById("add");
element.onclick = function() {
  // console.log("woot");
  var ele = document.getElementsByClassName("row")[0];
  var clone = ele.cloneNode(true);
  var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  document.querySelector('#container').appendChild(clone);
}
```

```html
<div id="title">
  <h1>Monthly Run Operations Assessment</h1>
</div>

<div id="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-20" id="row-one">
      <label for="name">1. </label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-60">
      <input type="text" id="op" name="op" placeholder="Insert operation here">
    </div>

    <div class="col-20" id="symbol">
      <img src="file:///C:/Users/user/Downloads/plus-circle-solid.svg" id="add">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="submit">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: This gave me almost the exact same behavior I have. It shows inside the container (CSS rules for the container apply), but not above the button.